# Binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Fraction' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, templates

[EDIT]
I am writing a template class with type argument `T`. In one of the functions member of that class, a variable with type `T` is expected to be written to a `std::ofstream` object. Everything is fine until I instantiate this class with a custom type argument `Fraction`. The error occurs although I did overload the `operator <<`.

```
// collection.h
#include <fstream>
template<typename T>
class Collection
{
public:
    void writeToFile();
private:    
    T val;
};

template<typename T>
inline void Collection<T>::writeToFile()
{
    std::ofstream file("output.txt");
    file << val;

}

// Fraction.cpp
#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& str, const Fraction& f)
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer:**

You answer need to declare `operator <<` with a line like this in `Fraction.h`, and `#include "Fraction.h"` before the code that uses it:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& str, const Fraction& f);
```

The concept of declarations vs definitions is fundamental to C++ (and C), so if you don't understand the distinction, search the web about it now to save yourself any more confusion.

Edit: **Old answer:**

Are you sure that you are really just doing `file << arr[i]` and not `file << somethingElse << arr[i]`? Because if you do the latter, then the static type of `file << somethingElse` is likely to be `std::ostream&` rather than `std::ofstream&`. In that case, the solution is to change `operator<< (..., Fraction)` to accept (and return) a general `std::ostream&` rather than `std::ofstream&`.

Edit: Another possibility: you need to make sure the declaration of `operator<< (..., Fraction)` is visible from the place you instantiate `Collection<Fraction>` (i.e. the declaraction of `operator<<` is above it).

Comment: You really should wait for the OP to provide a [mcve].  Right now these are just guesses.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I can guess if I want to! It's only my time I'm choosing to waste.

Comment: I've just edited the question to make it clearer and more precise.

Comment: @Rickie I have updated my answer, although without seeing the contents of `Fraction.h` (if such a file exists) it's still guesswork.